# python test script

Tags: python

I am trying to automate a test script for a website

I have the following error

```
    import urllib , urllib2 , cookielib , random ,datetime,time,sys


  cookiejar = cookielib.CookieJar() 
  urlOpener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar))
  urllib2.install_opener(urlOpener)


  username=username.strip()

  values = {'username': username, 'password': 'password'}  #user input

  data = urllib.urlencode(values)

 request = urllib2.Request('http://141.168.25.182/',data)

 url = urlOpener.open(request)


    File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
 File "/usr/lib/python2.4/urllib2.py", line 364, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/urllib2.py", line 471, in http_response
response = self.parent.error(
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/urllib2.py", line 402, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/urllib2.py", line 337, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/urllib2.py", line 480, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: what is this error printed on the screen

Comment: Hint 1.  Post the actual question in the title.  "python test script" is not a question.  It's a very, very bad title.  Hint 2: Format your code correctly so the indentation is correct.  Hint 3: Actually have a question.  An error message is not a question.  Unless you take the hint and fix your question, you may not get much help at all.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions that might help you

**urlencode function is different from what you think**

```
>>> from urllib import urlencode
>>> values = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'}
>>> data = urlencode(values)
>>> data
'username=username&password=password'
>>>
```

**request method arguments are again incorrect**

When you do this the, data is the request payload

```
request = urllib2.Request('http://141.168.25.182/',data)
```

**What you want to do is authenticate yourself.**

This will depend on what type of authentication server expects. The following serves for basic authentication using urllib2. Read the module docs for more detail.

```
import urllib2
auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(user='..', passwd='...')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen('url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using mechanize. That way it would less hassles. Your code would look something like this

```
import mechanize
base_url = "http://someurl"
login_url = base_url + "/login"
protected_url = base_url + "/potected"
b = mechanize.Browser()
b.visit(login_url)
b.add_password(base_url, "user", "secret", "some Realm")
b.open(login_url) 
b.open(protected_url)
```

You can also use mechanize's form submission and .click methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate tests for a web application you should use selenium and do something like.

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Create an instance of a browser
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

# Open homepage
browser.get("http://141.168.25.182")

# Find username and password fields (i do not know what ids your input fields actually have)
username_input = browser.find_element_by_id("username")
password_input = browser.find_element_by_id("password")

# Fill in username and password fields
username_input.send_keys("test_username")
password_input.send_keys("test_password")

# Find and click on the login button
browser.find_element_by_id("login").click()

# Check that you are signed in by finding a sign out button
browser.find_element_by_id("signout")
```